# How can I show that $Tr_{A}(Tr_{a}(M))=Tr_{A}(M)$ $M$ is a Module and $A$ is a class of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A$ a class of modules and let be $Tr_{A}(M)=\sum \{Imh | h:U \rightarrow M  \text{  for some   } U\in A \}$
SHow that
$Tr_{A}(Tr_{a}(M))=Tr_{A}(M)$

The first contention is quick because $Tr_{A}(Tr_{a}(M))\leq Tr_{A}(M)$

but the other one im stuck i take $x\in Tr_{A}(M)$
so $x = \sum imf $ for $f \in Hom(U,M) $ with $U\in A$ and i thini i have to obtain homomorphism in $Hom(A,Tr_A(M))$

but idk how any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathscr U$ be a class of $R$-modules.

**Definition.** We say that an $R$-module $L$ is *generated by $\mathscr U$* if there is a family $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ of elements of $\mathscr U$ and an epimorphism $\bigoplus_{i \in I} U_i \to L$.

Now, let $M$ be an $R$-module.
Define
$$\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}
\text{Tr}_\mathscr U(M) := \sum \{\im h : U \in \mathscr U,\, h \in \text{Hom}_R(U,M)\},
$$
which is a submodule of $M$.

**Proposition.** $\text{Tr}_\mathscr U(M)$ is the largest submodule of $M$ generated by $\mathscr U$.

*Proof*:
First, if we index $\bigcup_{U \in \mathscr U} \text{Hom}_R(U,M)$ as $(h_\alpha \colon U_\alpha \to M)_{\alpha \in A}$, this family induces a morphism $\bigoplus_{\alpha \in A} U_\alpha \to M$ whose image is $$\sum_{\alpha \in A} \im h_\alpha = \text{Tr}_\mathscr U(M).$$ It follows that $\text{Tr}_\mathscr U(M)$ is, indeed, generated by $\mathscr U$.

Next, if $L$ is a submodule of $M$ generated by $\mathscr U$, then there is a family $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ of elements of $\mathscr U$ and an epimorphism $p \colon \bigoplus_{i \in I} U_i \to L$. Thus, if $(\iota_j \colon U_j \to \bigoplus_{i \in I} U_i)_{j \in I}$ is the family of canonical injections and $i \colon L \to M$ is the inclusion map, then
$$
L = \im(ip) = \sum_{i \in I} \im(ip \iota_i) \subseteq \text{Tr}_\mathscr U(M).
$$
So, every submodule of $M$ generated by $\mathscr U$ is smaller than $\text{Tr}_\mathscr U(M)$. $\square$

**Corollary 1.** $M$ is generated by $\mathscr U$ if and only if $\text{Tr}_\mathscr U(M)=M$.

**Corollary 2.** $\text{Tr}_\mathscr U(\text{Tr}_\mathscr U(M)) = \text{Tr}_\mathscr U(M)$.

---

#### Reference:

Anderson, F. W. & Fuller, K. R. *Rings and Categories of Modules*. Second Edition. Page 109.